# Interpretation of VAR for non normal distribution!

Tags: r, distributions, vector-autoregression, risk

I want to compute the VAR and expected shortfall for log returns of monthly wholesale gas and electricity prices.

The data is not normally distributed and I only have 72 observation for each.

I haven't done any normality tests yet.

some stat of log ret

Electricity

Skew:0.45

Kurt:6.77

mean:0.0004126

sd:0.0877

Gas

Skew:1.39

Kurt:7.499

mean:-0.0026

sd:0.0935

My Question is if I use qnorm from R are the values for VAR still reliable?

also, would VAR and CVAR be used by an energy copmany? I mean they do buy energy in the wholesale market (which I assume is in form of contracts that they will have to sell if they do not need), but it feels like my judgement is missing something.

Comment: If the data's not normally distributed, then no, you can't use `qnorm`. Try comparing the empirical quantiles from your data to the ones from a normal distribution, like in a QQ-plot. It should be obvious that they are not the same.

Comment: so what other risk measurement I could use for a non-normal distribution? I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: VaR  can also be used for non nornal distribution....it is just a certaint quantile of the loss distribution. Please use VaR and not VAR...the latter  often refers to a vector autoregression.